# vagrant shared storage - docker container mysql - persistent volume - not coming up

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, vagrant, shared-directory

I tried multiple times with no luck and the results are going nowhere.

My set up is something like this:

- windows 10 host
- virtual box latest version
- guest VM is ubuntu latest minimal (command line)
- using vagrant to create VMs and share folders between host and guest VM

My code, Dockerfile, and Docker-compose files are saved in shared folder say (/vagrant/test) so I can easily access them from the Windows host.

From guest VM: (file permissions)

```
vagrant@dev-env-testing:/vagrant/test$ ll
drwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Apr 19 12:33 ./        
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root    4096 Apr 14 12:50 ../       
drwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr 14 10:30 .vagrant/      
-rwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant 1072 Apr 14 13:36 Vagrantfile*        
-rwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr 19 11:23 a*     
drwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr 19 12:33 code/         
drwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Apr 19 12:28 mysql-data/      
-rwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr 19 12:29 mysqlcontainer_bug_sharefolder.txt*
```

I also added the user "vagrant" in the group: `999(systemd-coredump)`

```
vagrant@dev-env-testing:/vagrant$ id
uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd),997(docker),999(systemd-coredump)
```

For testing I'm using this command to create a container:

```
docker run -d --name=test-mysql4 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -p 6604:3306 -v /vagrant/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql MySQL
```

here, I'm trying to create a persistent volume (mounted on a host shared folder `/vagrant/mysql-data`) for my_sql container but the container creation is failing.

Scenario 1:

> /vagrant/mysql-data: has no data in this folder.

docker logs test-mysql4

```
2021-04-19 12:28:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-19 12:28:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-04-19 12:28:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-19 12:28:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-04-19T12:28:37.465722Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2021-04-19T12:28:37.472616Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-04-19T12:28:37.478227Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-04-19T12:28:41.252791Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 95 in a file operation.
2021-04-19T12:28:41.252961Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 95 means 'Operation not supported'
2021-04-19T12:28:41.253274Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./undo_001: 'Linux aio' returned OS error 195. Cannot continue operation
2021-04-19T12:28:41.253413Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

or I get this error

Scenario 2:
/vagrant/mysql-data: has below files,

```
/vagrant/mysql-data$ ls

'#ib_16384_0.dblwr'  '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'   ib_logfile1   ib_logfile101   
ibdata1   undo_001   undo_002   undo_1_trunc.log   undo_2_trunc.log
```

```
2021-04-19 12:25:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-19 12:25:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-04-19 12:25:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-19 12:25:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-04-19T12:25:20.641591Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2021-04-19T12:25:20.645008Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2021-04-19T12:25:20.645019Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-04-19T12:25:20.645069Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-04-19T12:25:20.645195Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
vagrant@rma-dev-env-testing:/vagrant/mysql-data$ ls
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This post is of low quality, please edit your post and apply some proper formatting

Comment: Is this in any way related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164323/vagrant-shared-storage-docker-compose-container-mysql-persistent-volume?