# vagrant shared storage - docker compose - container mysql - persistent volume - not showing up

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, dockerfile, vagrant, vagrantfile

i tried multiple times with no luck and results are going nowhere.

my set up is something like this:

- windows 10 host
- virtual box latest version
- guest vm is ubuntu latest minimal(commandline)
- using vagrant to create vms and share folders between host and guest vm.

vm user and group details

```
 #id
  uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd),120(mysql),997(docker),999(systemd-coredump)
```

mycode, Dockerfile and Docker-compose files are saved in shared folder say(/vagrant/test) so i can easily access from windows host.

from guest vm: (file permissions)

```
vagrant@dev-env-testing:/vagrant/test$ ll
total 9
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Apr 19 14:30 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Apr 19 12:41 ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr 19 14:05 data/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  308 Apr 19 14:30 docker-compose-file.yml*
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr 14 14:41 env/
```

im getting this below error:

Scenario 1:

```
 cat docker-compose-file.yml                  // there is no rw enable for volume
version: '3'
services:
   mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_test
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql.env
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "6620:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Error

```
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2021-04-19T13:11:26.510762Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2021-04-19T13:11:26.514472Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010460] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
2021-04-19T13:11:26.514480Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-04-19T13:11:26.514531Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-04-19T13:11:26.514657Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
vagrant@rma-dev-env-testing:~/host_share_folder/rma4/mysql-alpha/mysql-test$
```

scenario 2:

cat docker-compose-file.yml         // rw enabled for volume

```
version: '3'
services:
   mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_test
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql.env
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "6620:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
```

errors:

```
2021-04-19 14:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-04-19T14:31:39.529706Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 45
2021-04-19T14:31:39.532827Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2021-04-19T14:31:39.532834Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-04-19T14:31:39.532899Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-04-19T14:31:39.533038Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-04-19 14:31:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-19 14:31:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-04-19 14:31:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-19 14:31:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-04-19T14:31:43.363006Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 44
2021-04-19T14:31:43.366296Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2021-04-19T14:31:43.366304Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-04-19T14:31:43.366619Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-04-19T14:31:43.366831Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

ANy help is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this in any way related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67162521/vagrant-shared-storage-docker-container-mysql-persistent-volume-not-coming?

Comment: yh the only difference is: one is docker written and the other is docker-compose written